# How to connect to the azure redis cache instance which is clustered with using redis clustered client in lettuce?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, lettuce

I have created azure redis cache instance with clustering enabled, When I tried to connect with redis clustered client using lettuce library by inputting host address it returns `Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs`?

```
        RedisURI redisUri = RedisURI.Builder.redis("redis-xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1-mz.ec2.cloud.rlrcp.com:14489")
                .withPassword("passwaord").build();
        RedisClusterClient clusterClient = RedisClusterClient
                .create(redisUri);
        StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String> connection
                = clusterClient.connect();
```

Is there any issues in above code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of lettuce client version if it is compatible with the redis version.

Example, lettuce version below 5.0.4 is not compatible with redis version 6 due to change in cluster commands in redis.